# Numpy operations for generating a 2D array from a 3D array

Tags: numpy

I have an array A with shape [2, 512, 21128]  and another list [7,41]

I want to create a new array with shape [2,21128] from A[0,7,:] and A[1,41,:].

I can use a loop to do such things, is there any convenient way to do this? I try to find it online but I actually do not know how to ask this question.

Comment: Do you mean the other list is literally `[7, 41]`? Can you clarify what indices of `A` you want to slice? Does `[0, 7, :]` mean you want the zeroth index of the first dimension, 7th index of the second, and all indices of the third? It would help if you reduced the sizes of your arrays and posted an example input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use advanced indexing:

```
arr = np.random.rand(2, 512, 21128)
out = arr[[0, 1], [7, 41]]
```

`out.shape`:

```
(2, 21128)
```